# WinRT Storing Session State Between Page Navigation

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, session-state

I am new to WinRT and was playing around with session state.  I am navigating to a page to collect data and then want to return to the main page.  Just before navigation I am using:

```
SuspensionManager.SessionState["CurrentState"] = someObject;
```

The object contains lists of other mildly complex objects, etc...  All seems to be working but is this the correct way to use the Suspension Manager?

I have looked at other posts on the topic and some people report that it is necessary to use [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes to all the classes that are serialized.  I omitted them and it still works, (getting the data across pages).  So what is the recommended approach?

Comment: Session state need to be serializable. Try app suspend and shutdown flow using command 'suspend and shutdown' while debugging the app after the app has set the session state. It will likely throw exception in SuspensionManager.save method. so, using datacontract attributes to make your sessionstate object (someObject) will be right thing.

Answer (score 1):

I may be reading too much into one aspect your question, but the role of `SuspensionManager` and `SessionState` is to store just enough information to bring your application back to the place the user left it *if* the application is actually terminated while it's suspended.

In the [Windows 8 application lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh986968.aspx), your app gets 'suspended' if another app comes to the foreground.  While your app is suspended all of its state is retained in memory, and if reactivated (you flip back to it) everything* is restored "for free".

A suspended app could, however, also be terminated by the OS (b/c of memory pressure, for instance) and there is no opportunity to react to that scenario in your app, so what you are really doing with `SessionState` is storing **what's necessary** to 'recreate' the last place the user was at IF the application had actually terminated. It's essentially an insurance policy: if the application is merely suspended, `SessionState` isn't really needed.

The 'what's necessary' is the grey area, I *could* store all of the information about say a user profile that was in progress OR I could save just the userid that indexes into my persistent storage of all the user profile data.  I generally have more of a minimalist view and will retain as little as possible in `SessionState` - I make the analogy that I don't need to remember everything, I only need to remember how/where to get/find everything.

There's an implication as well in your question that you're using `SessionState` to pass information between pages in your app, and that's not really the intent.  Each page of your app is typically connected with a view model, and when you interact with a page of that app, you'd update the view model and drive additional screens and experiences from the changes already in the view model.  Leaving one screen of your app and returning the main one would also imply to me that you've persisted what ever information you collected - certainly to the view model, but also to something persistent like a data base or local storage.  When you revisit that page, you'd then pull the data back out of your view model (or that persistent storage); the main page doesn't need that information so why hold on to it?

Lastly, since you mentioned being new to WinRT, you may want to check out [App Builder](http://aka.ms/8in30SO), which pulls together a number of resources in consumable chunks to lead you through building an app over a period of 30-days (though all material is available, so you can consume at any pace you want :))  The discussion of lifecycle management that's germane to your question comes in on Day 17 of that sequence.

*"everything is restored for free" doesn't necessarily mean you don't have any work to do when an app comes out of the suspended state. There may be stale data that requires refreshing, and connections or other transient or short-lived entities may need to be refreshed/recreated.